# Danger overflow

Tags: plumbing

My downstairs toilet for the second time has just overflowed with backup.  I have changed the toilet and poured draino down it last time.  My upstairs toilets are fine, my sinks downstairs are fine.  But, it has happened within three weeks and no one used it at time of overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Without more detail (type of system: septic and leech field or city line) it's difficult to answer with accuracy. Here are some general ideas that could help clear the lines: stop using drain clearing solutions (caustic or acidic). Used excessively they can corrode cast pipe and ruin the balance of septic tanks. You'll have better results clearing a stopped drain with a plunger (faster and safer) or a 3/8" cable. I'd look for the cleanout for the main house line, usually a few feet off the outside wall. It could be in the cellar (if you have one), but try snaking the cable from there. Lastly, run a garden hose that has been pushed down the roof stack to clear any blockage that may be affecting the venting in the drain line. Also, if you have one , make sure the septic tank doesn't need to be pumped (this probably isn't causing the problem).

Comment: This might also be a vent-pipe problem.